# Case replies to emails from org wide address lose original sender

Tags: email, email-alert, organization-wide

Our configuration:

- Org wide address "Our Org Name" with email "OurOrg24@ourorg.com"
- Email alerts set to send using that org wide address
- That mailbox has two auto-forward rules, one for cases and one for work orders - inbound message is auto-forwarded to the right mailbox (lets call the SF mailbox "ourorgcasemailbox@salesforce.com"
- The forwarding rules are setup using end user configurations in outlook 365

What happens:

- Email is sent to customer from our org
- Email comes from "OurOrg24@ourorg.com"
- Customer replies to "OurOrg24@ourorg.com"
- Email is forwarded to "ourorgcasemailbox@salesforce.com"

The problem:

- The inbound email is attached to case, shows as from "OurOrg24@ourorg.com", and reply/reply-all only have "OurOrg24@ourorg.com" as available address

What we want:

- The inbound email should come in as from the original sender with all the other addresses and cc addresses available

What is the best practice here?  I suspect the autoforwarding set up as a client is the problem.  Can our exchange team do a better server side rule to do an "invisible forward" or something?

Answer (score 1):

I think email forwarding has been setup at Exchange server. You need to setup Email relay properly. Refer [Set Up Email Relay](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&type=5) and also work with Corporate Email Service team for configuration and setup at their end.

> You can set up an email relay for Salesforce-generated email by configuring Salesforce to automatically route email through your company’s Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server. If your company sends email from more than one email domain, you can configure an email relay for each domain.

Comment: This looks like it's the right direction - but we also still get emails in this 'OurOrg24" email that don't need to be forwarded direct to SF.  Can these email relays be rule based at the subject line level? Like only forward emails with the subject line containing case object ref id types?

Comment: I think that forwarding can be possible, you need to check with Email Service team